# JS FormData giving UncaughtTypeError when the HTML form data seems okay

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Here's the HTML code:

```html
    <div class="some_class">
            <form id="some_acc">
                <p>First Name</p>
                <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Enter your first name">
                <p>Last Name</p>
                <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Enter your last name">
                <p>Date of Birth</p>
                <input type="date" id="dob" name="dob" placeholder="Enter your date of birth">
                <p>Email</p>
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
                <p>Gender</p>
                <div class="fieldset_account">
                    <fieldset>
                        <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female">
                        <label for="female">Female</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male">
                        <label for="male">Male</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="Other" name="gender" value="other">
                        <label for="other">Other</label>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <p>Choose no.</p>
                <div class="acc_no">
                    <fieldset>
                        <input type="radio" id="regular" name="account_type" value="regular">
                        <label for="account_type">Acc 1</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="zero_bal" name="account_type" value="zero_bal">
                        <label for="account_type">Acc 2</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="children_acc" name="account_type" value="children_acc">
                        <label for="account_type">Acc 3</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="sr_cit_acc" name="account_type" value="sr_cit_acc">
                        <label for="account_type">Acc 4</label>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <p>Remarks</p>
                <div id="textarea_bio">
                    <textarea name="bio" id="bio" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                </div>

                <br><br><input type="submit" value="Submit">

            </form>
        </div>
```

Here's the JS:

```js
function FormDataToJSON(FormElement){    
    var formData = new FormData(FormElement);
    var ConvertedJSON= {};
    for (const [key, value]  of formData.entries())
    {
        ConvertedJSON[key] = value;
    }

    return ConvertedJSON
}

var ReceivedJSON = FormDataToJSON(document.getElementById('some_acc'));

console.log(ReceivedJSON);
```

The error I'm getting is this:
`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'FormData': parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLFormElement'.`

Doesn't seem like there's anything wrong with the HTML form data. I'm guessing the radio buttons are the issue, but when I comment them out and try again, the error persists. What is going wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Multiple same ids (`some_acc`) in the document?

Comment: @Teemu nah this is the only thing in the document

Comment: If that's the case, your code [works as it is](https://jsfiddle.net/8tx163wh/). The error message clearly tells, that you're not passing a form element to `FormData` constructor, check the argument before calling `FormData`.